# Loop through file to get totals per person

Tags: c#

This is a sample from a payroll file I have to work with, it lists employee number, different types of earnings, & check date.  The goal is to get a subtotal per employee that lists the employee's total wages and other earnings.  I can't get my head around how to do this, can someone offer some suggestions?  I'm trying to do this in C#.  Some employees may have only one line, other employees may have lines with no regular wage types, only deductions/earnings (bonuses, insurance, etc...)

```
240 TN  DP  800.00  1696.65 .00 .00 .00 .00 65  46.20   11/10/11
240 TN  DP  800.00  1696.65 .00 .00 .00 .00 66  124.83  11/10/11
240 TN  DP  800.00  1696.65 .00 .00 .00 .00 72  5.27    11/10/11
240 TN  DP  800.00  1696.65 .00 .00 .00 .00 ZC  1933.75 11/10/11
240 TN  DP  800.00  1643.55 .00 .00 .00 .00 65  46.20   11/25/11
240 TN  DP  800.00  1643.55 .00 .00 .00 .00 66  122.18  11/25/11
240 TN  DP  800.00  1643.55 .00 .00 .00 .00 72  5.27    11/25/11
240 TN  DP  800.00  1643.55 .00 .00 .00 .00 ZC  1893.87 11/25/11
240 TN  DP  .00 .00 .00 .00 400.00  .00 66  20.00   12/09/11
240 TN  DP  800.00  1595.25 .00 80.00   .00 .00 65  46.20   12/09/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 65  .00 07/08/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 67  .00 07/08/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 69  .00 07/08/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 72  .00 07/08/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 74  .00 07/08/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 ZC  1299.03 07/08/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 65  181.85  07/22/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 67  12.46   07/22/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 69  .00 07/22/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 72  22.15   07/22/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 74  .00 07/22/11
242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 ZC  1124.70 07/22/11
```

Edit: In response to some questions, the fields are, in order from left to right:  employee#, state, dept, regular wage, overtime wage, vacation wage, holiday wage, sick wage, special wage, earning code, earning amount, check date.  I need to get a total per employee for each field, while making sure not to add a person's wages more than once for each check date.

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to add numbers? How to read numbers? How to find numbers? ...?

Comment: Can you elaborate and add what you have so far?  Also, you should also check out LINQ group by statements.

Comment: What does each column represent? I'm assuming one tells me which person it is and the rest are ??? What total of what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a text file you should read it and then elaborate the data. So this is what I would do:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(path);
```

Then for each element (line) in the array I would split it per data:

```
 __Data1___ ______________Data2_______________D3_ __D4__ ___Data5___
|          |                                |    |      |           |
 240 TN  DP  800.00  1696.65 .00 .00 .00 .00 65  46.20   11/10/11
 240 TN  DP  800.00  1696.65 .00 .00 .00 .00 66  124.83  11/10/11
 240 TN  DP  800.00  1696.65 .00 .00 .00 .00 72  5.27    11/10/11
 240 TN  DP  800.00  1696.65 .00 .00 .00 .00 ZC  1933.75 11/10/11
 240 TN  DP  800.00  1643.55 .00 .00 .00 .00 65  46.20   11/25/11
 240 TN  DP  800.00  1643.55 .00 .00 .00 .00 66  122.18  11/25/11
 240 TN  DP  800.00  1643.55 .00 .00 .00 .00 72  5.27    11/25/11
 240 TN  DP  800.00  1643.55 .00 .00 .00 .00 ZC  1893.87 11/25/11
 240 TN  DP  .00 .00 .00 .00 400.00  .00 66  20.00   12/09/11
 240 TN  DP  800.00  1595.25 .00 80.00   .00 .00 65  46.20   12/09/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 65  .00 07/08/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 67  .00 07/08/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 69  .00 07/08/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 72  .00 07/08/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 74  .00 07/08/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 ZC  1299.03 07/08/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 65  181.85  07/22/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 67  12.46   07/22/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 69  .00 07/22/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 72  22.15   07/22/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 74  .00 07/22/11
 242 TN  DP  1538.46 .00 .00 .00 .00 .00 ZC  1124.70 07/22/11
```

So I'd create a class and take the data that I need:

```
class Data
{
    public string Data1;
    public string Data2;
    public string Data3;
    public string Data4;
    public string Data5;
}
```

---

```
List<Data> myList = new List<Data>();

//Split lines
foreach(string s in lines)
{
   string[] buffer = s.Split(' '); //split by space

   Data data = new Data();
   data.Data1 = string.Concat(buffer.Take(3).ToArray());
   data.Data2 = string.Concat(buffer.Skip(3).Take(6).ToArray());
   data.Data3 = string.Concat(buffer.Skip(9).Take(1).ToArray());
   data.Data4 = string.Concat(buffer.Skip(10).Take(1).ToArray());
   data.Data5 = string.Concat(buffer.Skip(11).Take().ToArray());

   myList.Add(data);
}
```